# Why does my session resets when I add value in 2nd page then go back to original one?

Tags: php, session

So I have 2 pages. On 1st one I start a session array. Then I redirect to 2nd page. There I add a value to session array. But When I go back to 1st page session array resets to 0 values. I did put session_start() at the begining of both pages.

page 1

```
<?php

session_start();
$shopping_cart = array();
$_SESSION['cart'] = $shopping_cart;



print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
#Array ( ) 
?>
```

page 2

```
<?php

session_start();
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], "test");
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
#Array ([0] => test) 
?>
```

Comment: We can't possibly help you debug your issue if you don't post your code. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show us the code, or at least some example code that demonstrates this issue i.e. a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It should not do this, so we have to guess you have done something wrong in your code

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: How do you know what is in the session as you dont look at it in `page1` SHow us the output from a `print_r($_SESSION);` in `page1`

Comment: Hmm, when I go back to 1st page and then back to the 2nd one session array still stores values from before but it doesn't transfer them to page 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this logically. Lets remove the complication of the real SESSION and fake it for demo purposes

In page 1 you do

```
$shopping_cart = array();
$SES['cart'] = $shopping_cart;
print_r($SES);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

In page 2 you do

```
array_push($SES['cart'], "test");
print_r($SES);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )

)
```

Then you go back to Page 1 and DESTROY what was in the session by re-initializing it to a blank array

```
$shopping_cart = array();
$SES['cart'] = $shopping_cart;
print_r($SES);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Now if you had first checked if it was a good idea to re-initialise the session first, like this

```
$shopping_cart = array();
if ( !isset($SES['cart']) ) {
    $SES['cart'] = $shopping_cart;
}

print_r($SES);
```

You would get output like

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )

)
```

which would contain the data created in `page2`

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `$_Session` superglobal every time the first page loads.
Use:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $shopping_cart = array();
        $_SESSION['cart'] = $shopping_cart;
    }

    print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
?>
```

Comment: Finally got there